# Clear content of specific Grid column and row

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to change content of specific Grid column and row on button click event. I'm able to get it's row and column, but I can't make it to dissapear.

I'm creating new UserControl on `CreateLabel` button and adding it to specific `Grid` column and row.

Here is XAML Code:

```
<Window x:Class="DHL.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DHL"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="DHL Parcel" Height="500" Width="1000">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="RoundedButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFCB1F1F"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border CornerRadius="5" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="1">
                        <ContentPresenter>

                        </ContentPresenter>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Button.Effect">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DropShadowEffect Color="Black" Direction="320" ShadowDepth="3" BlurRadius="5" Opacity="0.5" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Name="gridzik">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,0,5">
            <Button Style="{StaticResource RoundedButton}" Name="CreateLabel"
                Content="Crate consingment" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center"
                Width="130" Click="CreateLabel_Click" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,5">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="19*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="11*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Style="{StaticResource RoundedButton}" Name="CheckLabels"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Content="Check consingment"
                TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center"
                Width="130" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="10,0" Click="CheckLabels_Click" />
        </Grid>


    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">

        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

And here is code behind:

```
private void CreateLabel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CreateLabel cl = new CreateLabel();
        gridzik.Children.Add(cl);
        Grid.SetColumn(cl, 1);
        Grid.SetRow(cl, 0);
        cl.dok_idm_textBox.Focus();
    }
```

What I'm trying to do with `CheckLabels` button is to clear `Grid Grid.Column="1"` content. Here is how I'm trying to do it:

```
private void CheckLabels_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (UIElement item in gridzik.Children)
        {
            if (Grid.GetColumn(item) == 1 && Grid.GetRow(item) == 0)
            {
                gridzik.Children.Remove(item);
                break;
            }
        }

        Label labelek = new Label();
        labelek.Content = "JHEEK";
        gridzik.Children.Add(labelek);
        Grid.SetColumn(labelek, 1);
        Grid.SetRow(labelek, 0);
    }
```

I found out that it's removing but it can't dissapear and I don't know why. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need dynamic content, you could Just use 2 grids and set their visibility property accordingly

```
private void CheckLabels_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     grid1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
     grid2.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Comment: I want to change this specific column/row content depending on button click. For example: When I click CreateLabel button, column Content change to CreateLabel UserControl, then when I click CheckLabels it changes to CheckLabels UserControl.

Comment: @fanarek Sorry i had a typo. anyway i was just suggesting you put all your controls in the grid, or use a subgrid, and just make the controls visible or collapsed instead

Comment: That would be easiest way, i guess. Thanks for your suggestion.